# Angular Mat-expansion-panel:while selecting the checkbox, the panel is expanded and the content present moves upward (Screenshot attached)?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

[image]I am working on  multiple angular mat checkbox along with other data using mat-expansion-panel based on response from the server. I am able to generate multiple mat-expansion-panel based on the serve response, But whenever I am clicking on a checkbox ,the content in the expansion panel shifts upwards and the panel gets expanded.

I have already tried `<mat-checkbox formControlName="i" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()>"` as I found in an answer in Stackoverflow, but this doesnt work

```
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let testcase of solutionTestList;index as PI;">
    <mat-expansion-panel [id]="'testcase' + PI">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header [collapsedHeight]="'60px'" 
       [expandedHeight]="'60px'">
            <div class="custom-row">
            <div class="col-md-1" align="center">
            <label formArrayName="testCaseSelected">
            <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="PI" >
            </mat-checkbox>
            </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce on stackblitz. It is working as accepted https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-initial-setup-eet3g1.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbyqhq ,I am not able to reproduce exactly ,as there are some css files missing(which I cant add) .

Comment: Thanks, event.stopPropagation() is also working for me , when I applied it on formArray ,But the content is shifting upwards on selection , i applied css position property also but still the conntent moves upwards on checkbox selection

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

Finally I found out that the content shifting up is caused by **no content** inside the `<mat-checkbox>` tag. As soon as there is content, the checkbox stays where it is:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-checkbox color="primary" 
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    CONTENT NEEDED HERE!
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  Content
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

This behavior can be seen here side-by-side:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8bffp

It can be solved by adding a `&nbsp;` inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Testcase should be within `mat-checkbox`  tag. Also replace div with span to show in single line after checkbox.

```
          <div class="col-md-12" align="center">               
            <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="PI" >
           <span class="col-md-4">
            {{testcase.identifier}}
          </span>
          <span class="col-md-4">
            {{testcase.testTitle}}
          </span>
          <span class="col-md-4">
            {{testcase.vnf}}
          </span>
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but actually while using col-md-2 in span tag, the alignment  gets changed and the space gets reduced ,https://ibb.co/XsVwjcW  ,this is the image,I have placed all the span elements in a div of size 12.

Comment: Try setting `col-md-12` on main div and `col-md-4` on each span.

Comment: I have tried that but still not working , my code is here http://collabedit.com/a583q

Comment: Show code of header row which contains IDENTIFIER TEST TITLE VNF

Comment: I have updated the code in http://collabedit.com/a583q , but on clicking of a row the check box also gets selected is it possible to remove this.

Comment: Remove the label tag. This will stop checkbox selection on click of text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198711/discussion-between-ranjeet8082-and-yatharth-mishra).